# Quantum mechanical description of diamagnetism in hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electric-current

I am trying to understand the source of diamagnetism for atoms. Classically, we can explain diamagnetism using Lenz's law. I wanted to see whether a full quantum mechanical description gives the same.

I start with the hydrogen atom in an electromagnetic field.
\begin{align}
H &= \frac{(-i\nabla-A)^2}{2m} - \frac{Ze}{r}\\
& = -\nabla^2/2m - i (A.\nabla + \nabla.A)/2m + A^2/2m -Ze/r 
\end{align}

I would have to solve Maxwell's equations self consistently with the hydrogen atom:

$$(\nabla^2 - \partial_t^2)A = \langle J\rangle$$
Where $\langle J\rangle$ is the current operator

To get diamagnetism, we need to get $\langle J\rangle \propto A$ in the Coulomb gauge. I can write out the current operator as $\langle J\rangle = i/2m\langle \phi|\nabla \phi\rangle - A/2m $.  Considering the vector potential as a small perturbation, the paramagnetic current expectation value evaluated for unperturbed hydrogen atom orbitals should be zero. I can evaluate this for the hydrogen atom 1s-orbital wavefunction and I can already see that the radial paramagnetic current is non-zero:
$$\int dr ~ r^2 e^{-r/a}\partial_r e^{-r/a} * [\mbox{angular~integral}]$$

So then what is the source of diamagnetism in the hydrogen atom?